# Add Swagger dependencies only for development enviroment

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, swagger, swashbuckle

According to Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio), we should add swagger dependencies for all envs.

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
```

But enable UI only for dev.

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

Why? Doesn't it make more sense to add dependencies only for dev env too? Like:

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you do as you propose?

Comment: (I feel like this is one of those cases where either **a)** it works, and so you need to [ask Microsoft](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues) "why do your docs say X when Y works and seems more sensible?" - it's off topic here because we cannot authoritatively speak to what Microsoft teams are thinking, so there is no question to answer here or, **b)** it doesn't work and hence there is no question to answer here ..)

Comment: It is worked as I expected: On dev you load swagger dependencies and swagger configuration - application+swagger works. On test you don't load swagger dependencies and swagger configuration - only application works.

Comment: Then you're in situation a) - you need to ask Microsoft what their thinking is (I linked the GitHub for the dotnet docs) , or maybe they will agree and update their documentation. It's not really something we can help with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddSwaggerGen` method contains service registrations for swagger to work.
Here what docs say to us:

> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen Injects an implementation of ISwaggerProvider that can be used by the above component. This particular implementation generates OpenApiDocument(s) from your routes, controllers and models

If for some environment you are excluding:

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
```

You could exclude `AddSwaggerGen` as well without any problems.